# want to render an API from external JSON File but getting an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I am taking a local .json file and rendering it in React. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState = { tree: [] }
}

componentDidMount() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
        var nodes;
        nodes = result;
        if (this.isMounted()) {
            this.setState({ tree: nodes });
        }
    }.bind(this));
}

render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <h4>Results from ajax</h4>
            {this.state.tree} //here i get json array
            <h4>Tree</h4>
            {this.state.tree.map(function(nodes) {
                return <li key={nodes.hits.hits._score}>{nodes.hits.hits._id}</li>
            })}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
./src/components/app.js
Line 11:  '$' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

help me, please. I also tried configuring ESLint in package.json at env, by turning JQuery : true.

Comment: You have to import jquery manually. You can use `fetch()` which is default method to make api requests

Comment: `{this.state.tree}` will produce error as react cannot print object. Try `{JSON.stringyfy(this.state.tree)}`

Comment: I personally prefer `axios` for doing requests in a react environment. JQuery is good for dom manipulation and lots of other things but it's not really necessary when working with UI frameworks like React

Answer (score 0):

install jquery using npm like this

> npm install jquery --save

Import jquery on your component

```
import $ from 'jquery' //In case of ES 6

var $ = require('jquery'); //In case of ES5.
```